# how to create JSON object from firebase dashboard?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to create JSON obejct not abel to find those options??

can't find how to add a JSON object in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), can anyone help ?

Comment: Only i can add child

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on "+" button before add a key value to create a child.

Comment: https://s31.postimg.org/wip6ljqcb/Screen_Shot_2016_06_17_at_2_27_02_PM.png

Comment: It isn't what I'm asking for. In your database you've just one JSON object and you create different child from here.

Comment: can i make like this from dashboard? 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/p9GVo.png

Comment: Yes you can easily.

Answer (score 5):

Before you enter a value for a node click on the plus sign to create a child under that node.
[image: click on the plus of a node to make a child node]

Answer (score 2):

if you wants to create a json object in *firebase* *database* with multiple values then add a '**key**' and assign its value as a **JSON object** like: **`{"name":"Jhon", "age":"22", "exp":"3 yrs"}`**.